# Is possible to remove duplicates in Power BI based on a time interval between the data?

Tags: duplicates, powerbi, formula, powerbi-desktop

I have a list of leads data.

The table has a lot of infos like date, name, email, mobile number, etc.

However, *some of these leads are duplicates*: the same person generated more than one lead

What i want to do is to remove the duplicate leads.
The problem is, to be considered a duplicated lead, the email or the mobile number must appear in more than one row, **in a time interval of 30 days**.
And only those who come next must be considered duplicated. The first one is always a not duplicated lead.

E.g.

1) If Jones generated a lead in **01/01/20** with his email abc@abc.com and then generate another lead **10 days** after, in 10/01/20. The first lead is a single lead (not duplicated) and this second lead **must be considered duplicate**.

2) If Maria generated a lead in **01/01/20** with her email xyz@abc.com and then generate another lead **40 days** after, in 10/02/20. The first lead is a single lead (not duplicated) and this second lead also **must be considered single (or not duplicate)**.

To mark the lead as duplicate or not, i want to generate a new column with the time between the last lead of the same person (same email or same mobile number)

Then generate a new column with the label "**Duplicate**" or "**Not Duplicate**" based on the time showed on the last column. If its > than 30 days, that is a single lead. Otherwise (<30 days) is a duplicate lead.

E.g picture:

[image]

**Can someone please help me on how to do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the lag/lead data is not very straight forward in Power BI. You will have to use a combination of `EARLIER`and some aggregate function to get the specific result. For your specific scenario, the following calculation might work:

```
Day Difference = 
        VAR name1 = 'Table'[Name]
        VAR Lastdate1 = MAXX(FILTER('Table','Table'[Name]=name1 && 'Table'[date]<EARLIER('Table'[date])),'Table'[date]) 
RETURN 
        IF(
            DATEDIFF(Lastdate1,'Table'[date],DAY)=BLANK(),
            100,
            DATEDIFF(Lastdate1,'Table'[date],DAY))
```

Once the column is created, you can filter for all records <=30 to get the result you are looking for. I have replaced the blanks with 100, so that the original records don't get removed when applying the condition.

If you are looking for the "Tag" value, then the following calculation will get you the tag values directly:

```
Tag = 
        VAR name1 = 'Table'[Name]
        VAR Lastdate1 = MAXX(FILTER('Table','Table'[Name]=name1 && 'Table'[date]<EARLIER('Table'[date])),'Table'[date]) 
RETURN 
        IF(IF(
            DATEDIFF(Lastdate1,'Table'[date],DAY)=BLANK(),
            100,
            DATEDIFF(Lastdate1,'Table'[date],DAY))<=30,"Duplicate","Single")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

It Really helped, and was really close of what i need.

I Just have some doubts

1) Why did you use the MAXX function between the Date<EARLIER function and the Date itself, instead of just taking the Date of the row and use it?

2) In the case where I have more than one lead in the same Date, the calculation returns 100 in all of them.
Is there a way in which one of them return 100 and the others return 0, or something like that?

Comment: Cause i need to consider just one of them as s "Single" lead and the others are also "Duplicate"

Thanks

Comment: To answer qn 1, it was specifically used that way to get the previous date from the current row. We are trying to get the maximum of all dates before the current date, hence using the earlier condition.

Comment: To answer qn 2, you would have to create a rank function to eliminate such cases